# App crashes in UIScrollView with index out of bounds error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, nsmutablearray

In my iPhone app, I am using FGallery from github to display a photo gallery.
My problem is sometimes when I multiple clicks on an image in the gallery(I think it is mostly for the first image), my app crashes with the following error message.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4294967295 beyond
>   bounds [0 .. 1]'

My code for passing the array to the FGallery class is here.

**in .h**

```
@interface ProdDetails : UIViewController<FGalleryViewControllerDelegate>   {
    NSMutableArray *networkImages;
    FGalleryViewController *networkGallery;
}
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *networkImages;
@property(strong,nonatomic) FGalleryViewController *networkGallery;
-(void)setNetworkImages;
```

**in .m**

```
-(void)setNetworkImages {

    self.networkImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *data = [prodDet objectForKey:@"model_details"];
    for (id eachDic in data) {

        NSString *eachUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",IMG_INIT_URL,[eachDic objectForKey:@"model_imgurl"]];
        eachUrl = [common replaceStringWhiteSpaceinUrl:eachUrl];
        [self.networkImages addObject:eachUrl];
    }
}
-(void)showProductImageGallery    {
    networkGallery = [[FGalleryViewController alloc]initWithPhotoSource:self];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 1.0;
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;

    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:networkGallery animated:NO];
}
```

Anyone please help me to solve the issue.

**EDIT**

Thanks to All. At last I found the problem. The problem is in FGallery.

```
- (void)scrollingHasEnded {

    _isScrolling = NO;

    NSUInteger newIndex = fabs(floor( _scroller.contentOffset.x / _scroller.frame.size.width ));
    //NSLog(@"%f,%f,%i",_scroller.contentOffset.x,_scroller.frame.size.width,newIndex);
    // don't proceed if the user has been scrolling, but didn't really go anywhere.
    if( newIndex == _currentIndex )
        return;

    // clear previous
    [self unloadFullsizeImageWithIndex:_currentIndex];

    _currentIndex = newIndex;
    [self updateTitle];
    [self updateButtons];
    [self loadFullsizeImageWithIndex:_currentIndex];
    [self preloadThumbnailImages];
}
```

When we scroll first image to the previous ,  _scroller.contentOffset.x is become negative.
So `floor( _scroller.contentOffset.x / _scroller.frame.size.width )` results negative index.
I just added fabs function to result a positive index

Comment: check self.networkImages contains image url

Comment: yes it contains image urls. i can scroll through the images for normal touches. But app crahes when i scroll fastly.

Answer (score 0):

The error description says that, `it because you (or FGallery) trying to access object from`networkImages`array from the index which is not exist (out of bound)!`, with this code we can't help you exactly --- **as its not enough!** If you can't find any solution with `FGallery` you should look after to **[MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)**. Its quite easy to use I found.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code

```
NSMutableArray *data = [prodDet objectForKey:@"model_details"];
```

instead of

```
NSArray *data = [prodDet objectForKey:@"model_details"];
```